# SQL Server Management Studio 2017 Issue Logging in with new laptop

Tags: sql-server, sql

I just bought a new laptop. I installed SSMS 2017 but when I try to login like I used to with my old laptop (putting my computer name as the server) I get this error:

[image: error mesage]

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Did you install the database engine too? If so, did you do it as a default instance or named instance? Please see [this site](https://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/what-version-of-sql-server-do-i-have/) to get info on what SQL Servers you have installed on your laptop